# How to change domain name from "LocalHost" to ipaddress in Jdeveloper?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

When i run any application from JDeveloper, the page opening with the URL keeping "*LocalHost*" as a domain name,
eg: http://*localhost*:7101/Testing/faces/index.jsf

How can i change the domain name from "localHost" to my system's ipaddress. So that whenever i execute the page, the page should open with the ipaddress and not with "localhost", like http://*10.34.65.175*:7101/Testing/faces/index.jsf

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Deploy your application on the WLS that is located on `10.34.65.175`. Any reason you don't want to use localhost?

Answer (score 0):

As Sydney asked, why would you want this?
The only reason I could think of is that you want other users (within the same network as you) to access your WLS. If so you can do the following:

- Go to your admin console (htpp://localhost:7101/console)
- Click on 'Environment'
- Click on 'Servers'
- Click on 'DefaultServer(admin)'
- In 'Listen Address' enter your local IP
- Reboot your WLS and it should be accessible by other users on http:// your_local_ip:7101/Testing/faces/index.jsf